# node.js breaking the execution of my website

Tags: node.js, express

I have a website with over 100k monthly users which I first coded 6 years ago with vanilla PHP5.4 and despite not updating it(I have not done any change all this time) it still works fine.

I want to rewrite the whole code and I am thinking of choosing express.js this time, but once I will finish coding it, I won't have time to manage and keep updating it. My question is, if in the next 5-6 years, I don't work on it, will the website still keep working or the dependencies will break it? Will I need to keep it up to date with the latest versions?

Comment: So long you don't update it and you keep using the packages you installed, the website will keep running.

Comment: @JohnKennedy thanks for answer. What if, at some point, I decide to make some minor design changes, will that cause any problems?

Comment: As long as you specify version of each module in the `package.json` you will be fine, And if you wanted to update just change version of the module you want to update and etc.

Comment: In the minor change too, as long as you don't change server node version and your project's modules version; everything would be fine, but if your change needed a new version of a package or a new library, maybe it take a little time to implement.

Comment: @Yahya ok, thank you for the answer.